# ColdFusion 2016 Administration page doesn't load on cloned machine

Tags: iis, coldfusion, iis-8, coldfusion-2016

I recently configured and hardened an installation of ColdFusion 2016 + IIS 8 in preparation for a upgrade from CF9. I was able to load all of our web, configure our data sources, and get everything pointed in the right direction. I was able to test that this server was working as expected so we created an image of this machine and loaded it onto another server. We put the cloned machine on it's own IP and gave it it's own domain name in IIS. So here's the problem, the ColdFusion admin pages doesn't work. It works on the original machine, and most of our web apps work on the cloned machine.  There are some web apps acting up on the clone machine, but I believe I can solve that issue if I could just get to the CF Administrator page. Currently when we try to reach it at thissite.xyz:8500/CFIDE/administrator we get a blank white page. I created a virtual directory for it in IIS and get the same results.

Comment: Did you get the issue resolved?

Comment: Technically no. We created a new imagine of the working server and restored that image to the server with the bad admin page. It works now but we were never able to figure out what was happening. I'd still very much like to know what was wrong in case it happens again.